# How prevent newline after span using css?

Tags: html, css

I view quiz Moodle using WS(Webservice) but not using js and css from moodle.
i cannot change code but can using css.
Please help me, how to make CSS to prevent newline after radio button?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keVxy.png)

```html
<div class="answer">
  <div class="r0">
    <input type="radio" name="q21:2_answer" value="0" id="q21:2_answer0" aria-labelledby="q21:2_answer0_label">
    <div class="d-flex w-auto" id="q21:2_answer0_label" data-region="answer-label">
      <span class="answernumber">a. </span>
      <div class="flex-fill ml-1">
        <p>&gt;</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add your relevant css? remember div is a block so probably you div after input is in a new line

Comment: Use a `label` instead of `div`

Comment: I using WS moodle, please don't modification for output.

Comment: Quick solution put in the .answer class display:flex; or add in the div the class d-flex "<div class="answer d-flex">..." 

Nots a good solution but this will work

Answer (score 1):

You can use `label` instead of `div` it will fix your issue

```html
<div class="answer">
  <div class="r0">
    <input type="radio" name="q21:2_answer" value="0" id="q21:2_answer0" aria-labelledby="q21:2_answer0_label">
    <label class="d-flex w-auto" id="q21:2_answer0_label" data-region="answer-label">
      <span class="answernumber">a. &gt;</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/checks-radios/#radios

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have updated the explanation Thanks

Comment: Work, but must change code.

Comment: @PrimaYanuaristya Use label is the correct way

Comment: Hi @Prima if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```html
<style>
  .w-auto {
    display: contents;
  }
</style>

<div class="answer">
  <div class="r0">
    <input type="radio" name="q21:2_answer" value="0" id="q21:2_answer0" aria-labelledby="q21:2_answer0_label">
    <div class="d-flex w-auto" id="q21:2_answer0_label" data-region="answer-label">
      <span class="answernumber">a. &gt;</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).